# Microsoft BotFramework Web Chat - Custom Control

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, adaptive-cards

I am customizing Microsoft Web Chat with adaptive cards. i have a specific requirement to load a custom control i have created a new template, customcontrol.tsx.
When rendering i have modified the adaptive cards and wrapped the adaptive card container around the customcontrol.tsx.

`<AdaptiveCardContainer className="hero" card={ cardBuilder.card } onImageLoad={ props.onImageLoad } onCardAction={ props.onCardAction } onClick={ onCardAction(attachment.content.tap) }>
    <CustomControl  propInfo={attachment.content} />
</AdaptiveCardContainer>`

I have the cards being rendered on the container and the content inside. On Click of Card on Container, i want to get the information from the Custom Control Drop-Down Selected value, what would be the right way to get the information or propagate the information from custom control to the card click on the adaptive container. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you will need to start by providing the WebChat control with a custom AdaptiveCards build, and add your custom control to the type registry: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/52fced5b28eb063b00d25cfb40c24530678bdf62/source/nodejs/adaptivecards/src/card-elements.ts#L3773

Comment: We did customize the adaptive cards to add styling to all html attributes and started adding custom react components to support specific UX elements , right now looks great